# Finding $\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t)$, where $y$ is a solution to $\frac{dy}{dt}=e^yy^2(y-1)(y-2)^3(y-3)^5$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y(t)$ be solution to the boundary value problem
>   $$\frac{dy}{dt}=e^yy^2(y-1)(y-2)^3(y-3)^5,\qquad y(3)=\frac{1}{2}$$
>   Find $$\lim_{t\to+\infty}y(t)$$

**My Try:** For $y\lt0$, $\frac{dy}{dt}\lt0$. For $0\lt y\lt1$, $\frac{dy}{dt}\lt0$. For $1\lt y\lt2$, $\frac{dy}{dt}\gt0$. For $2\lt y\lt3$, $\frac{dy}{dt}\lt0$. For $y\gt3$, $\frac{dy}{dt}\gt0$.   Hence for $y=\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{dy}{dt}\lt0$, then $y(t)$ decrease as $t$ increase. But I don't know how to determine if $y(t)$ will decrease below $0$. Also if $y(t) $ go below $0$, then still have $\frac{dy}{dt}\lt0$. Now whether $y(t) $ will go to negative infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y=0$ is a solution and the right side is differentiable, so the uniqueness theorem applies. Thus crossing the value zero is not possible. The same goes for the other fixed points $y=1,2,3$.

Comment: Ok, I see. Can we conclude that $\lim_{t \to \infty}y(t)=0$ since $\frac{dy}{dt}\lt 0$. Still get trouble in this step.

Comment: Yes, because you know that $y(t)$ is monotonous, bounded on both sides, and at the limit point you get $0=y'(\infty)=f(y(\infty))$, thus the limit point has to be a root of $f$, the solution can not stall at some intermediate point.